# What is a word for completely different from other people?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, writing-style

I know that "polar opposite" could be used, but I feel that it does not fit in my paragraph. I am writing about a teacher that differs from my other teachers because she pushes us, even when we complain to her about it, because she knows it is in our best interest, as opposed to teachers that simply hand out busy work.

Comment: Use *unique*. As it stands, your question is unclear and too broad at this point.

Comment: From Googling "synonyms for unique":  remarkable, special, singular, exceptional, noteworthy, notable, extraordinary; unequaled, unparalleled, unmatched, unsurpassed, unrivaled, peerless, incomparable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "stands out from the crowd" comes to mind.

> By pushing us to do our best [name] stands out from the crowd that demands from us only minimal effort.